# Auto Close Chrome Browser or Mozila Firefox After 30 second

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, batch-file

I'm using this script for the purpose of opening 5 url at a time...! 
Now i want to auto close this browser after 30 sec.

how it will be work ?? any idea?

```
@echo off

START chrome.exe javascript:document. "http://google.com"

exit
```

Comment: Please add what you have already tried or researched to your post. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

START chrome.exe javascript:document. "http://google.com"
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:30  >nul 2>&1
taskkill /im chrome.exe /f

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) from Windows Sysinternals Tools.

To get the pause use `timeout 30`

Something like this:

```
@echo off
START chrome.exe javascript:document. "http://google.com"
... more stuff here ...
TIMEOUT 30
PSKILL chrome.exe
```